# Encrypt the password string in web.config

Tags: c#, encryption, configuration-files

How can I encrypt the password string in web.config?

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="guess@gmail.com" password="test" port="587" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: [encrypt web config section](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=encrypt+web+config+section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are best off encrypting that whole section of the file, as there is tooling built in for this, and it is automatically decrypted when the config file is read (so there's no need to change your code). This is [described fully on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx), and uses the `aspnet_regiis.exe` tool.

Answer (score 1):

Check this Scott gu blog : [**Encrypting Web.Config Values in ASP.NET 2.0**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx)

[**Encrypting Custom Configuration Sections**](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/01/08/encrypting-custom-configuration-sections.aspx)

```
<configSections>
   <section 
      name="sampleSection" 
      type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" 
   />
</configSections>

<MySecrets
   FavoriteMusic="Disco" 
   FavoriteLanguage="COBOL" 
   DreamJob="Dancing in the opening ceremonies of the Olympics" 
/>
```

Encrypt MySecrets

```
aspnet_regiis -pef MySecrets
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [David M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11413095/909882):

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pe "system.net/mailSettings/smtp" -app "/myapp"
```

Please note that aspnet_regiis is case sensitive, so make sure to capitalize the 'S' in mailSettings.